# converting "1984-03-25 02:00:00" to POSIX gives NA

Tags: r, datetime, posix, na

While converting a vector of date-time to POSIXlt, just one particular time "25-Mar-1984-02:00" "is converted to POSIXlt but returns NA! So, this row was getting omitted in my analysis/plots.

```
is.na(as.POSIXlt("25-Mar-1984-02:00",format = "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M"))
is.na(as.POSIXlt("25-Mar-1984-03:00",format = "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M"))
is.na(as.POSIXlt("25-Mar-1984-01:00",format = "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M"))
is.na(as.POSIXlt("24-Mar-1984-02:00",format = "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M"))
is.na(as.POSIXlt("26-Mar-1984-02:00",format = "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M"))
```

returns TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE.

but

```
class(as.POSIXlt("25-Mar-1984-02:00",format = "%d-%b-%Y-%H:%M"))
```

returns
    [1] "POSIXlt" "POSIXt"

Isn't that strange? How can I get it to be "not NA"?

Comment: All 5 lines `is.na...` above return `FALSE` for me

Comment: Likely because 1984-03-25 02:00 is when DST occurred in your timezone (which you don't specify), so 2AM doesn't exist (1:59:59.999 is followed by 3:00:00.000).

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich yep, it was due to the DST! Thanks for pointing out!

Comment: @JoshuaUlrich you should make that an answer - astute observation which deserves upvoting

Comment: @NickK: your wish is my command... posted. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you don't say what your timezone is, this looks like Daylight Saving Time (DST) issue.  In timezones that use DST, there will be a day where the hour "jumps" from 1:59:59.999 to 3:00:00.000.  This means that any times in the 2AM hour do not exist on this day.

My guess is that 1984-03-25 02:00:00 is when DST occurs in your local timezone.